# Proof need to draw first or not, is the first person who draw will in inferior position？

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions

Two person,  A and B are challenged to draw a single piece of paper that marked cross from a box that contains X number of papers, without repetition. The person who draws the marked cross paper first will be punished.

**The Question:**

If A offers B the choice whether he wants to draw first or not, B is afraid that he will draw that marked cross paper in the first draw. On the other hand, if B draws a blank paper in the first round, A chances to draw that piece of paper that marked cross are increased.

Whether B needs to take the offer to draw first or not?

Sorry for that formatting, I have lacked knowledge about this topic, I had tried to solve this question based on my notes, but always cannot get the idea, may I ask about the theory of this question?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. While the body of your question is acceptable, the question title is not informative enough. Please change it to a better one which gives some information about your main question.

Answer (score 0):

If $x=1$ (there is only one paper in the box), it will be the marked one, so whoever goes first will take it and be punished.

If $x\ge 2$, then the person going first has a $\frac1x$ chance to draw it on their first draw. The person going second (if they need to draw at all), have then a $\frac1{x-1}$ chance to draw the marked paper on their first draw. But as I said, maybe they don't need to draw at all. $\frac1{x-1}$ is the conditional probability that they draw the marked paper on their first draw, on the condition that the player going first didn't draw it.

So the actual probability that the second player draws the marked paper on their first draw is $\frac1{x-1}$ multiplied with the probability that the second player needs to draw at all, which is $1-\frac1x=\frac{x}{x-1}$. So the probability that the second player draws the marked paper on their first draw is $\frac1{x-1}\frac{x}{x-1}=\frac1x$, which is the same as the first player!

So if at least 2 papers are involved, each player will draw the marked paper on their first draw with the same probability $\frac1x$, so there is no advantage or disadvantage at that stage. Of course, now the game continues, and we are basically playing the same game as before, now with $x-2$ papers.

That leads to the result that if $x$ is even, no player will have an advantage. If the drawing reaches the state where just 2 papers remain, the marked paper will be drawn, obviously, and each player will do it with probability $\frac12$.

If $x$ is odd however, it means that while the game is "fair" for the next drawing of each player if there are at least $3$ papers left, it is "unfair" for the first player if only 1 paper ist left, as we saw in the beginning. So for odd $x$ there is an advantage going second. So if the number of papers in the box are unknown to the players, B should take the offer and go second (doesn't matter for even $x$, advantage for odd $x$).

---

Another way to see that result, and even calculate the probabilities for each $x$ that the first or second player gets punished is the following:

The players draw the papers randomly from the box. So, besides determining who goes first, the players have no real agency in the process, they don't make an actual decision.

That means the process can be modelled that some arbiter randomly shuffles the papers with a uniform distribution to put them in some order (all orders are equally likely). That means the marked paper has an equal probability to come up in any of the $x$ positions.

Then the first player takes the first paper. If it isn't the marked one, the second player takes the second paper. If it isn't the marked one, the first player takes the third paper, a.s.o. alternating.

But since there is only one marked paper, one can say that each player takes all of their respective papers until all are gone, then they look at their papers and find out how has lost (because they got the marked paper).

If we consider the process that way, it's clear that the player going first got the 1st, 3rd, 5th, ... paper (all odd ones) while the player going second got all the even ones.

But since the marked paper had an equal probability to end up in any position, the probability for each player to have the marked paper is easily calulated. If $x$ is even, there are an equal number of even and odd positions, so each player gots half ($\frac{x}2$) papers, so they each have the marked one with probability $\frac1x\frac{x}2=\frac12$.

If $x$ is odd, there is one more odd position in the order of the papers (it starts with the odd $1$ and ends with the odd $x$). There are $\frac{x+1}2$ odd positions and $\frac{x-1}2$ even positions. So the player going first has probability $\frac{x+1}{2x}=\frac12+\frac1{2x}$ to be punished, while the player going second has probability $\frac{x-1}{2x}=\frac12-\frac1{2x}$ to be punished.

As can be seen and seems natural, the difference becomes smaller if $x$ gets bigger.